# Stripe Customer Portal: How to update the subscription with multiple products?

Tags: stripes

I have a subscription with multiple products, how can I update this subscription in the customer portal? (I implemented the customer portal, but the Update Plan button is hidden with the subscription with multiple products.)

I know this is the limitation of stripe but is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

I asked Stripe and got a solution: **Cancel the old subscription and resubscribe**.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhgP2.png)